# Saving image from httpResponce

Tags: android, bitmap, httpresponse

I have to download image from `httpResponse` and save it on internal storage on android device. I have this block of code trying to do that:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

Bitmap logo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("logo.png",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    logo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    fos.close();
}
```

But I dont get the result I need. Saved image is does not open with image viewvers and its slighly bigger in size too. Image to download is 1.71 KB and the result is 2.01 KB. any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried dealing with `BitmapFactory.Options` ?

Comment: Have you tried aborting your `httpResponse` (httpResponse.abort()) after calling `decodeStream` ?

Comment: @MocialovBoris httpResponse has no method abort() and casting to `HttpRequestBase` throws exception. I'll try some `bitmapFactory.Options`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the real problem in your code but you can try this code if you want,this code ran without any problem for me

To save into internal memory...

```
   File fileWithinMyDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();  
    try 
          {
              StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
              .permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
           URL url = new URL("http://t2.gstatic.com  /images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjZgUffqqe2mKKb5VOrDNd-ZxD7sJOU7WAHlFAy6PLbtXpyQZYdw");
           File file = new File( fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()  + "/" +"sun.jpg");
           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
           ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
           int current = 0;
           while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
           {
            baf.append((byte) current);
           }

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
           fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
           fos.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e("download", e.getMessage());
        }
```

To load image from internal memory..

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .permitAll().build();
           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
          mImgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgView1); 

          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()  + "/" +"sunn"+".file extension");
          mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```